# Typescript 4 nullish assignment (??=) not working in new CRA project

Tags: typescript, webpack, create-react-app

Typescript 4 supports [nullish assignment (??=)](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Logical_nullish_assignment). CRA 4 released yesterday says it supports TS 4. That operator works in the code editor, but when running `yarn start` I get:

```
Module parse failed: Unexpected token (14:10)
File was processed with these loaders:
 * ./node_modules/@pmmmwh/react-refresh-webpack-plugin/loader/index.js  
 * ./node_modules/babel-loader/lib/index.js
You may need an additional loader to handle the result of these loaders.
```

To reproduce the problem I just create a new app with CRA with Typescript support. Then just add the following lines to App.tsx:

```
const test = { a: 1 };
test.a ??= 2;
```

Any ideas? I don't know much about Babel/Webpack.

Comment: Update your babel version to latest

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. I mentioned that in the issue I just opened here: https://github.com/facebook/create-react-app/issues/9908

Answer (score 1):

I did the test and it feels like a bug/regression in CRA since these features have been around since 2019 (nullish coalescing was from TS 3.7 or sth like that). Same error occurs with plain js (plain js should also support the operators). CRA v4 (the major version!) was just released yesterday so this is quite likely.

While this gets fixed you might just stick with CRA v3, as manually fixing that might be painful.

Comment: Thanks for confirming the issue. I'll probably try sticking with CRA v4 for now and just not use that operator until it's fixed. It wasn't working in earlier versions either. I opened an issue here: https://github.com/facebook/create-react-app/issues/9908

Answer (score 0):

Do you have accesss to your webpack.config.js file?

Usually you need to add a loader (like `tslint-loader`), a tsconfig file and a rule in webpack config in order to let webpack transpile the TS code into JS.

If CRA doesn't let you modify that file without ejecting, there must be a way in which you can update the loader to the latest typescript specifications

Comment: Yes, I probably could find a way to fix it if I eject. But the reason I like CRA is that I don't like dealing with setting up dev envs and project config stuff much, so I'll just let them know and hope they fix it haha. I opened an issue here: https://github.com/facebook/create-react-app/issues/9908